# How to stop Adobe Experience Manager from storing binaries into local file system?

Tags: amazon-s3, aem

We are using Amazon S3 for storing our binaries and we just want to keep reference of those binaries into our local files system. Currently, binaries are getting stored in both S3 and local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to repository/datastore folder when you are using the S3 data store, that is your S3 cache. You can change the size of the cache and in theory reduce it some small number **but you cannot completely disable it**

`cacheSize=<size in bytes>`

in your S3 config file.

> Note that there is a practical lower limit to this number based on purge factor parameters. Setting this below 10% of your S3 bucket size will have lots of cache purge triggered and this will slow down your system. Changing it to zero will give a configuration error on startup.

Just for some background, the `path` property in your S3 config is the path to data store on a file system. This is because S3 datastore is implemented as a write through cache. All the S3 data is written on the file system and then asynchronously uploaded to the S3 bucket. The asynchronous uploads are controlled via other config in the same file (number of retries, threads etc.)

This write through cache gives a lot of performance boost to your application as write operations won't suffer from S3 net latency. You should, ideally, configure the cache size and purge ratio according to your disk requirements and performance efficiency rather than reducing it to bare minimum.

**UPDATED 28 March 2017**

Improved and updated the answer to reflect latest understanding.